# How can I turn on my dependencies in android studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I'm trying to customize a ready-made application I bought from code canyon. I have followed the documentation all the way through the installation of flutter, android studio, and visual studio plus all JDK tools.
However, at the point of getting dependencies, I cannot see the option to get dependencies for a file (main. dart) as it is on the documentation.

Below are images of how it appears on my documentation computer screen and my computer screen respectively.

**How it appears on the documentation computer screen**
[image: How it appears on the documentation computer screen]

**How it appears on my computer screen (note that my screen lacks the option Get dependencies)**
[image: How it appears on my computer screen (note that my screen lacks the option Get dependencies)]

Comment: It does not appear for you because you already have the dependencies. If you add a new dependency, it would show you too.

Comment: @stacktrace2234 is right. However, if you want to be sure, you can run in terminal: flutter pub get

Answer (score 1):

Open `pubspec.yaml`. You will find 3 options on top of editor

1. Pub get
2. Pub upgrade
3. Pub outdated

Click on `Pub get`, if you add a new package. Click on `Pub upgrade`, if you want to upgrade an existing package. (Note your package version should contain `^` to upgrade. Example `provider: ^6.0.0`). Click if to check if your package contains any deprecated classes.

or

You can run the following commands on terminal.

```
flutter pub get
```

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

```
flutter pub outdated
```

Comment: Thanks but it works for the file pubspec.yaml and the options appear (get pub, upgrade.etc) though it fails to show the options for the file main.dart. Something is wrong with this file main.dart.

Comment: It only appears at pubspec.yaml, if you fail to perform get or upgrade then it shows in other dart files (not just main.dart). Some times it may show even after performing get or upgrade on dart files. click ignore at that time. it works. How to Know whether you have done pub get or pub upgrade? check on the time of Message --- it will be less than a second.. usually in milli second if you have already performed get and upgrade.. based on your internet speed... otherwise it takes more than a second..

Answer (score 0):

Simply open your project directory in a terminal window and run

```
flutter pub get
```

That should work!